# hyperledger Composer - transaction failed

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Getting stuck while making transaction on composer-playground. Github [Link](https://github.com/aprilsnows/hyperledger-composer-supply-chain-network). It throws the error

> t: Instance org.hcsc.network.Commodity#ts1 has property company with type org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin that is not derived from org.hcsc.network.Trader [image: screenshot of error]

Comment: Please share your model file and logic script

Comment: https://github.com/aprilsnows/hyperledger-composer-supply-chain-network

Comment: @RThatcher Please go through the github link.

Answer (score 1):

In your definition of `Trace` you have a `--> Trader company`, and in your code you assign `me` (current participant) - BUT you have processed the transaction using an ID that is bound to the Network Admin (org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin)

You need to run the transaction as a Trader

1. Create a new Trader participant
2. Issue an ID to the participant
3. Select and use that ID
4. Run the transaction

BTW I notice that you are using a `new Date();` in your transaction - this is an example of a 'non-deterministic' value, and when you move to a multi-peer configuration this will fail.  It will fail because when the Fabric runs the transaction on Multi-peer and tries to find consensus, the timestamps will be fractionally different on each peer and the transaction will be rejected.  For the same reason you can't use random numbers in transactions.